# creating my own context processor in django

Tags: django, view, django-context

I have come to a point where I need to pass certain variables to all of my views (mostly custom authentication type variables).

I was told writing my own context processor was the best way to do this, but I am having some issues.

My settings file looks like this

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "sandbox.context_processors.say_hello", 
)
```

As you can see, I have a module called 'context_processors' and a function within that called 'say_hello'.

Which looks like

```
def say_hello(request):
        return {
            'say_hello':"Hello",
        }
```

Am I right to assume I can now do the following within my views?

```
{{ say_hello }}
```

Right now, this renders to nothing in my template.

My view looks like

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def test(request):
        return render_to_response("test.html")
```

Comment: I had the same problem and the solution here worked for me : [Use takes_context=True when using register.inclusion_tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59452521/5796086)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The context processor you have written should work.   The problem is in your view.

Are you positive that your view is being rendered with `RequestContext`?

For example:

```
def test_view(request):
    return render_to_response('template.html')
```

The view above will not use the context processors listed in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.  Make sure you are supplying a `RequestContext` like so:

```
def test_view(request):
    return render_to_response('template.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: The 'context_instance' is what was missing! Thanks TM

Comment: Follow up, how come i need this context_instance? How come i don't need this if i use django's auth system?

Comment: Django's built in views handle this for you (they use a `RequestContext`).  Think about the context processor that you made.  It takes `request` as an argument.  That means you need to somehow give the current request to the rendering logic. `RequestContext` basically just handles the simple logic of looping through all the context processors and passing the current request to them, then updating the page context with the results.

Comment: Could i modify my view to request the context?

Comment: @dotty Not sure what you mean by "request the context".

Comment: @TM.  `return render_to_response('template.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))` is old fasion, i think `return render(request,'template.html')` is more DRY

Comment: @suhail doesn't that require a special third-party decorator on the view function?   The answer is out of date in general (over 3 years old!),  probably these days there would be a class-based view here.

Answer (score 32):

According to the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext) you can use `render` as a shortcut instead of render_to_response with the context_instance argument:

> Alternatively, use the `render()` shortcut which is the same as a call to render_to_response() with a context_instance argument that forces the use of a RequestContext.

Comment: Indeed, these days that is possible.

Answer (score 23):

Let's say you have a file structure like this:

```
YourDjangoProject
├───project
│   ├───__init__.py
│   ├───asgi.py
│   ├───settings.py
│   ├───urls.py
│   └───wsgi.py
├───.env
├───manage.py
└───db.sqlite3
```

**1) Anywhere, create a context_processors.py file**

I'll create one in the project folder (with settings.py):

```
YourDjangoProject
└───project
    ├───...
    └───context_processors.py
```

**2) Create a function in context_processors.py that accepts a HttpRequest object as an argument and returns a dictionary**

A context processor is just a function that accepts an HttpRequest object as an argument and returns a dictionary.

Like this:

```
# project/context_processors.py

def site_email(request):
    return {'site_email': 'example@gmail.com'}
```

**3) Add this to your `context_processors` setting in `settings.py` (at the bottom for security reasons)**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'config' / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'project.context_processors.site_email',  # <- New context processor here
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

***Now you'll be able to access the 'site_email' template variable on every single django template across your whole site.***

Happy coding!

Comment: Very Very sorry @Zack But it's a really awesome answer. Given you an upvote. Really helped me to understand a very important concept of Django. Seen your profile You really have a Great vision for Humanity and the future. Hope to see you succeed in your vision. keep Smiling like that.

Answer (score 10):

Since Django 1.8 you register your custom context processors like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            'templates'
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'www.context_processors.instance',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

assuming your context processor is in app `www` in `context_processors.py`

Answer (score 2):

If you’re using Django’s `render_to_response()` shortcut to populate a template with the contents of a dictionary, your template will be passed a Context instance by default (not a `RequestContext`). To use a `RequestContext` in your template rendering, use the `render()` shortcut which is the same as a call to `render_to_response()` with a `context_instance` argument that forces the use of a `RequestContext`.