# Django - How to make a variable available to all templates?

Tags: python, django, django-nonrel

I would like to know how to pass a variable to all my templates, without repeating the same code on every method in my views.py file?

In the example below I would like to make categories (an array of category objects) available to all templates in the web app.

```
Eg: I would like to avoid writing 'categories':categories on every method. Is it possible?
```

**One view method**

```
def front_page(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    if is_logged_in(request) is False:
        return render_to_response('users/signup.html', {'is_logged_in': is_logged_in(request), 'categories':categories}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('users/front_page.html', {'is_logged_in': is_logged_in(request), 'categories':categories},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Another view method**

```
def another_view_method(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('eg/front_page.html', {'is_logged_in': is_logged_in(request), 'categories':categories},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: They are called `CONTEXT PROCESSORS`

Comment: [Sometimes we don't really need to create context processors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74041707/5675325).

Answer (score 152, accepted):

What you want is a context processor, and it's very easy to create one. Assuming you have an app named `custom_app`, follow the next steps:

- Add `custom_app` to  `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` (you've done it already, right?);
- Create a `context_processors.py` into `custom_app` folder;
- Add the following code to that new file:

  ```
  def categories_processor(request):
   categories = Category.objects.all()            
   return {'categories': categories}
  ```
- Add `context_processors.py` to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in `settings.py`

  ```
  TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += ("custom_app.context_processors.categories_processor", )
  ```

And now  you can use `{{categories}}` in all the templates :D

**As of Django 1.8**

To add a `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`, in the settings you must add the next code:

```
TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['context_processors'].append("custom_app.context_processors.categories_processor")
```

Or include that string directly in the `OPTIONS.context_processors` key in your `TEMPLATES` setting.

Comment: Is it possible to make this work for any app in the project, instead of just `custom_app`?

Comment: @jvannistelrooy Yes, it's possible.

Comment: This is so much easier to understand than other docs available elsewhere.  Thanks.  One thing: += doesn't work for me in D1.6.  Instead:  TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (...)

Comment: Does this also work for dynamic type queries such as ones that are dependent on which user is logged in? For example, what if I wanted notifications to be a global variable but only for the user that is logged in? I shouldn't do something like querying every single person's notification right? Or do I just do notifications.objects.all()

Comment: @EazyC As you can see the parameter of the function is a request, so you can get the logged user with request.user, and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: @EazyC It's a pleasure :D

Comment: Should the answer change with the newest Django? (bringing this up on Oct 2015)

Comment: I think instead of adding to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, which is deprecated since 1.8, you should add to the OPTIONS.context_processors list in TEMPLATES.

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres  is there a way to this in Django 3.x ?

Comment: @PoulaAdel check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/

Comment: [Another good example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66051857/5675325).