# Global variable for gogoleMap key in django project

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps

I need to open my gmap in a few pages:

```
{% block extra_js %}
    <script src="{%static 'js/map.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAZY5nutUGjjf4D...endOFKEY&callback=initMap"async defer></script>
{% endblock %}
```

and sometimes keys get expired. It's really annoying to change the key in every html file I have. Maybe I can make some sort of a global varialbe and store the key there? Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably this link will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/433162/641249

Answer (score 0):

Put this on you settings.py

```
TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['context_processors'].append("API_KEY : YOUR_API_KEY")
```

then use {{API_KEY}} on your template as a variable. for more info check: 
[Django - How to make a variable available to all templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901341/django-how-to-make-a-variable-available-to-all-templates)