# Django Context and Variables

Tags: python, django

I am currently using Django and Oscar to set up a shopping cart for someone.

I am also using the django-oscar-stores extension.

I was wondering if there is a way for me to incorporate the context of a django-oscar-stores view in to my other views and templates so I can use the variables to dynamically add the store information to the site.

So if I go to the view of the stores app I can call a variable in that template {{ store_list }} but if I am in any other view I cannot access this variable.

I understand why I cannot, but **I was wondering how I would give access to the store_list variable so that I can use it on every page** (so I can have the store information in the header of the site dynamically and not hard coded in to the template).

I am new to Django, so sorry if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass a variable to a specific template from your view function, you should use `context` kwargs, in django's [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut.

```
    return render(request, 'index.html', context={'store_list': store_list_var})
```

If you want to pass it to all templates, use [`context_processors`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901341/django-how-to-make-a-variable-available-to-all-templates).

Comment: Thanks a ton, context_processors was exactly what I needed.  I already have it up and running and now the variables are accessible across the whole site. Thanks again.