# Django: send context to 'base.html'

Tags: python, django

I have a nav bar item that is used to register/login. As, it's gonna be in different pages, I'm thinking of calling this form "once" for every page, in the 'base.html'.

I've found about the 'context processor' ([Django - How to make a variable available to all templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901341/django-how-to-make-a-variable-available-to-all-templates)), however, as I can see, it passess only a variable to all templates, in a function (**Doesn't** use a View class, with get and post methods).

For that, it uses a function like this one on the file:

**view.py**:

```
def categories_processor(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()            
    return {'categories': categories}
```

However, I'm using Class Views in my views.py, and, generally, I do pass the 'request', 'url to be rendered', 'context'. Like this:

**view.py**:

```
class RegistroClienteView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        ls_tipos_de_documento = TipoDocumento.objects.values_list('id', 'nombre_corto')
        form = ClienteCreationForm()
        context = {'form': form, 'ls_tipos_de_documento': ls_tipos_de_documento}
        return render(request, 'app_cliente/frontend/ingreso.html', context)

    def post(self, request):
        ls_tipos_de_documento = TipoDocumento.objects.values_list('id', 'nombre_corto')
        form = ClienteCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'app_cliente/frontend/ingreso.html', context)

        context = {'form': form, 'ls_tipos_de_documento': ls_tipos_de_documento}
        return render(request, 'app_cliente/frontend/ingreso.html', context)
```

My question is what to return in the View?

After following the steps for seetting up the 'context-processor.py', in this file, I have:

path: *app_cliente/context-processor.py*

File: **context-processor.py**:

*Please, notice that I'm only returning the context*

```
from app_cliente.forms import ClienteCreationForm
from django.views import View
from nucleo.models.tipo_documento import TipoDocumento


class RegistroClienteView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        ls_tipos_de_documento = TipoDocumento.objects.values_list('id', 'nombre_corto')
        form = ClienteCreationForm()
        context = {'form': form, 'ls_tipos_de_documento': ls_tipos_de_documento}
        return context

    def post(self, request):
        ls_tipos_de_documento = TipoDocumento.objects.values_list('id', 'nombre_corto')
        form = ClienteCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            context = {'form': form}
            return context

        context = {'form': form, 'ls_tipos_de_documento': ls_tipos_de_documento}
        return context
```

**Question:**

In my urls.py, in which url should this View called from?

Is this the correct approach?

**UPDATE 1:**

Let me clarify my question using this example posted in the comments:

```
url(r'^any-url-i-want/$', RegistroClienteView.as_view(), name='any-name-i-want'),
```

Here, `RegistroClienteView.as_view()` would render which template??? Remember that it only returns a context in the `context_processor.py` file.

Comment: In your question you say that you want a navbar element be present in all templates. What does it have todo with context processors?

Comment: "In my urls.py, in which url should this View called from?" You can set any url you want, as long as you pass the view. as in `url(r'^any-url-i-want/$', RegistroClienteView.as_view(), name='any-name-i-want'),`

Comment: @guillermochamorro in the navbar are the login/register forms. As is going to be in different pages, I want to call my view in 'base'.html' once for all.

Comment: @guillermochamorro, please, see the updated question. May you explain that? Ty.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace `return context` with `return render(request, 'PATH/TEMPLATE.html', context)`.

This also resolves your question which template it renders :-)

Comment: But it's going to be different templates. So, I don't want to hardcode a single 'PATH/TEMPLATE.html'. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

To have a navbar template in your base.html, create `templates/myapp/navbar.html` and then in your

**base.html**

```
...
include('myapp/navbar.html')
...
```

If you want to show the user name you can add in your `navbar.html`

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
{{ request.user.username }}
{% endif %}
```

If you want to add other data to your navbar, use context processors.

Use `TemplateView` in your view to define wich template to use:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class RegistroClienteView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'myapp/my_template.html'
    ...
```

Finally as stated in my comment:

You can set any url you want, as long as you pass the view. as in

```
url(r'^any-url-i-want/$', RegistroClienteView.as_view(), name='any-name-i-want'),
```

Comment: But it's going to be different templates. So, I don't want to hardcode a single 'PATH/TEMPLATE.html'. Is there a way to do it?  Or the only way is to create a View for every page that loads the navbar with the form?

Comment: @OmarGonzales I realize that you want to create an entire view in your context processor. You don't need to do that. First, context processor take as argument `request`, not `View`. If you have a form template in your base, *the form is rendered on every view*. What you change is the urls your template points to. So in your base.html you have a login form that points to your `url 'login'`, and a register form (remember, the form rendered in every view) that points to `url 'register'.`

Comment: Your views are available everywhere as long as you have an url pointing at them. Context processors are for having access to specific pieces of data across any template.