# How to receive context to base template django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-context

I have base template base.html and page.html and page2.html, who extend base.html

## page.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

## page2.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

I want to receive some context to base.html when i send request to page.html and page2.html

How can i do it? Real example, if it possible.

Now i write data to every view, but it is wrong way, i think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: send context to 'base.html'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894252/django-send-context-to-base-html)

Answer (score 0):

The base template receives the same context data as the templates extending it. So you can do something like this in the base template without problem.

```
#base.html
<title>{{ title }}</title>
```

Comment: yes, but i must add this context to every view, which extend base template. I don't want do it

Comment: Sounds like you need a context processor, refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893724/creating-my-own-context-processor-in-django