# django variable available to all the views

Tags: python, django, django-views

With context_processors it' s easy to define a callable which results variables available to all the templates. Is there any similar technique which makes a variable available to all the views? Is that somehow possible? Maybe with some workaround?

Django: 2.2
Python: 3.5.3

.

Comment: Make a class with the variable you want to and inherit that in each view class maybe?

Comment: What about global variables?

Comment: At this project there' re no class based view unfortunately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - How to make a variable available to all templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901341/django-how-to-make-a-variable-available-to-all-templates)

Comment: No, I needed for the views, not for the templates. However, custom middleware was working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to implement a custom Middleware.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/

This lets you execute custom code for every request and attach the results to the `request` object, which is then accessible in your view.

Comment: This works very fine, thanks. I did not think it' s so easy to write a simple middleware.

Answer (score 1):

You can try sending your variable to the context of each class based view by having a parent class and inheriting all the views from that.

```
class MyMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        myvariable = "myvariable"
        context['variable'] = myvariable
        return context

# then you can inherit any kind of view from this class.

class MyListView(MyMixin, ListView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ...  #additions to context(if any)
        return context
```

Or if you are using function based views, you can use a separate function which can update your context `dict`.

```
def update_context(context):  #you can pass the request object here if you need
    myvariable = "myvariable"
    context.update({"myvariable": myvariable})
    return context

def myrequest(request):
    ...
    context = {
        'blah': blah
    }
    new_context = update_context(context)
    return render(request, "app/index.html", new_context)
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are no class based view at the moment in this project.