# Webhook from Django 4.1 to python-telegram-bot 20.0a2

Tags: django, python-asyncio, webhooks, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I use the python-telegram-bot 20.0a2 library and Django 4.1

The bot runs by main.py script:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

---

Inside of the main script I also run `uvicorn` in the same ascynhronous context as `Application` instance

```py
# Run application and webserver together
async with application_tg:
    await application_tg.start()
    await server.serve()       # uvicorn
    await application_tg.stop()
```

---

**What is the problem?**
I use webhook for my bot
Django's `url.py` calls async `view` but the `view` can't get initalized Application instance of the bot.

**so the question is:**
How can to rearrange a scheme of interaction between `python-telegram-bot 20` and `Django 4.1` in a way that I can access `Application` instance from a Django hook?

*Addition*:
It's easy to achieve by using other frameworks such as `starlette` as it mentioned on the official wiki page of PTB library: https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a2/examples.customwebhookbot.html

---

My main script:
https://gist.github.com/SergSm/6843fadf505b826f83a10bf7eebc3fa0

my view:

```py
import json
from django.views import View
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from telegram import Update

from bot.tgbot.main import application_tg

async def telegram_handle(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
 
        await application_tg.update_queue.put(
            Update.de_json(data=json.loads(request.body), bot=application_tg.bot)
        )
 
        return JsonResponse({"ok": "POST processed"})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"ok": "GET processed"})
```

## UPDATE 1

I was desperate to make it run this way.
I tried to use `contextvars` module and read a lot of asyncio related stuff/

In the end I made an awful assumption that if I put my `python-telegram-bot` code into the `Django` view async function it's gonna work. But it does work!

And now I will try to wrap it using middleware to make my code cleaner

## UPDATE 2

If you want to use Django orm with sync functions you need to use @sync_to_async(thread_sensitive=False)

the **thread_sensitive=False** parameter is important in this case otherwise you will never get the result of awaitables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django variable available to all the views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55697465/django-variable-available-to-all-the-views). Also if you're using Django anyways, I'm wondering why you're using `uvicorn` for the webserver instead of having Django handle that as well

Comment: I use `uvicorn` instead of Django itself because it's the right way for a production https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/

Comment: @CallMeStag I will dig into using of Django middleware for this problem and will write the result later

Comment: ah okay, thanks for the clarification. I somehow thought that django had a built-in webserver …

Comment: Hey! Did you fix this? I’m kind of at the same zone :/

Comment: @CristianFavaroCarriço well yes but my code is a total mess. Some context: the main goal of my bot is to implement a telegram webapp using Heroku free tier(it'll shutdown soon). Some sort of a proof-of-concept. If you are still interested I will clean my code and share it on github. What do you think?

Comment: @CristianFavaroCarriço for now I may show you the gist with 2 main files for this trick. Here you are: https://gist.github.com/SergSm/0244b3c86d691c8ae31f4a1881f4ce54

Comment: Thanks.m, man. I’ll take a look and see if your code helps me. My thing is that I want to keep using Django db instead of running a different process in my server… don’t know if this is the best approach btw.