# How to put variable from database into base.html template?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working on a web page. There will be contact in the `footer` like email or telephone. This `footer` should be everywhere so it is in the `base.html` which is being extended by each `template/html`.

I've created a table called `ContactAdmin`, to provide simple and straightforward interface for admin to change his contact info. And here is the problem.

The `base.html` has no view (it is just for extending) so I don't know how to put there variable - `email`, `telephone` from table `ContactAdmin`. I thought about putting it into every view which is a huge overkill in my opinion.

So how to make **Django** to read this variables from database and put them into `base.html`?

*The **ContactAdmin** table should have just one row*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use context processors for this purpose. For instance:

yourapp/context_processors.py

```
def contact(request):
    from yourapp.models import ContactAdmin
    contacts = ContactAdmin.objects.all()

    return {
        'contacts': contact,  # Add 'contacts' to the context
    }
```

yourproject/settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'yourapp.context_processors.contact',
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I guess these contact settings are not going to change very often. So you may be interested in [caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/) the result of the query as well.

Answer (score 4):

You dont need to edit all views. Exactly for this scenario, django has [template context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext). The advantage here is, since the base template is still part of the templating language, and it has access to the `Context`, you just need to set these variables in your custom context processor, and everything should work as is.

Some examples on how to write your custom context processors:

- [StackOverflow Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893724/creating-my-own-context-processor-in-django)
- [Django example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)