# Django templates don't get the context variables

Tags: python, django

We are using Django 2.1 for [Speedy Net](https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net). I added an admin view for users - the URL of each user is the same URL of the user but with the prefix `"/admin/user"`. I defined the admin user prefix with a context processor:

```
def add_admin_user_prefix(request):
    if ((request.user.is_superuser) or (request.user.is_staff)):
        admin_user_prefix = "/admin/user"
    else:
        admin_user_prefix = ""
    return {
        'admin_user_prefix': admin_user_prefix,
    }
```

But the problem is, base templates and included templates don't see this variable. I don't use the `only` keyword when including templates. But still, base templates and included templates don't print anything when I print `{{ admin_user_prefix }}`. The prefix is to redirect the admin to the admin-specific user URL instead of the regular user URL. But I checked and the URLs are the regular URLs. In some cases the prefix is printed, and it seems to me that it's printed if it's not an included template and not a base template. What is the problem and How do I fix it?

from `speedy/core/settings/base.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            str(APP_DIR / 'templates'),
            str(ROOT_DIR / 'speedy/core/templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',

                'speedy.core.base.context_processors.active_url_name',
                'speedy.core.base.context_processors.settings',
                'speedy.core.base.context_processors.sites',
                'speedy.core.base.context_processors.speedy_net_domain',
                'speedy.core.base.context_processors.speedy_match_domain',
                'speedy.core.base.context_processors.add_admin_user_prefix',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

In some cases the prefix is printed, therefore the context is created. I'm checking the website as a user who is both superuser and staff.

The templates that are not printing `{{ admin_user_prefix }}` are either included in an include such as:

```
{% include 'admin/user_list_item.html' with user=user %}
```

Or they are base templates of the rendered template (`{% extends 'profiles/user_base.html' %}`).

This is the view:

```
class UserDetailView(UserMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'profiles/user_detail.html'

    def get_widget_kwargs(self):
        return {
            'request': self.request,
            'user': self.user,
            'viewer': self.request.user,
        }

    def get_widgets(self):
        widgets = []
        for widget_path in django_settings.USER_PROFILE_WIDGETS:
            widget_class = import_string(widget_path)
            widgets.append(widget_class(**self.get_widget_kwargs()))
        return widgets

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        cd = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        cd.update({
            'widgets': self.get_widgets(),
        })
        return cd
```

`profiles/user_detail.html` contains `{% extends 'profiles/user_detail_base.html' %}`, which contains `{% extends 'profiles/user_base.html' %}`, which contains `{{ admin_user_prefix }}` which doesn't display properly. The same tag in the widgets does display the admin user prefix.

My templates:

`speedy/net/templates/admin/profiles/user_detail.html`:

```
{% extends 'profiles/user_detail.html' %}

{% block user_tools %}{% endblock %}
```

`speedy/net/templates/profiles/user_detail.html`:

```
{% extends 'profiles/user_detail_base.html' %}

{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ user.name }} / {% block site_title %}{{ block.super }}{% endblock %}{% endblock %}
```

`speedy/core/templates/profiles/user_detail_base.html`:

```
{% extends 'profiles/user_base.html' %}

{% load i18n %}

{% block user_content_info %}
    <div class="row flex-wrap">
        {% for widget in widgets %}
            {{ widget.html }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

`speedy/core/templates/profiles/user_base.html`:

```
{% extends 'base_site.html' %}

{% load core_tags_and_filters %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load core_messages_tags %}
{% load rules %}

{% block content %}
    {% has_perm 'accounts.view_profile' request.user user as can_view_profile %}
    {% has_perm 'accounts.view_profile_header' request.user user as can_view_profile_header %}
    {% has_perm 'accounts.view_profile_info' request.user user as can_view_profile_info %}

    <div class="row justify-content-center">

        <div class="{% if site == speedy_match %}col-md-7{% else %}col-12{% endif %}">

            {% if can_view_profile_header %}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md">
                        <div class="page-header">
                            <h1>
                                <a href="{{ admin_user_prefix }}{% url 'profiles:user' slug=user.slug %}">{{ user.name|truncatechars:50 }}</a>{% block user_extra %}{% endblock %}
                            </h1>
                            <div class="text-muted">
                                {% block user_status %}
                                    {% if friendship_request_sent %}
                                        {% trans 'Friendship request sent' %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% if user_is_friend %}
                                        {% trans 'Your friend' context user.get_gender %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endblock %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-auto">
                        <div class="my-2">
                            {% block user_tools %}
                                {% include 'profiles/tools/tools.html' %}
                            {% endblock %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            {% endif %}

            {% if can_view_profile %}
                {% block user_content %}
                {% endblock %}
            {% else %}
                {% if can_view_profile_info %}
                    {% include 'profiles/block_warning.html' with user=request.user other=user %}
                {% else %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <a href="//{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}.{{ SPEEDY_NET_DOMAIN }}{{ admin_user_prefix }}{% url 'profiles:user' slug=user.slug %}">
                                {# ~~~~ TODO: remove "his/her" and setup strings in Python! #}
                                {% trans "This user doesn't match your profile, " context user.get_gender %}{% trans "but you can visit his/her Speedy Net profile. " context user.get_gender %}{% trans "View " context request.user.get_gender %}{% trans "user's profile on Speedy Net." context user.get_gender %}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            {% block user_content_info %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

I checked and found out that the problem is with a tag such as `{% profile_picture user '256x200' html_class="rounded-lg" %}`, which calls the following tag:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('accounts/profile_picture.html')
def profile_picture(user, geometry, with_link=True, html_class=''):
    return {
        'user': user,
        'geometry': geometry,
        'width': geometry.split('x')[0],
        'with_link': with_link,
        'html_class': html_class,
    }
```

The prefix not printed is only in the template `'accounts/profile_picture.html'`.

Comment: @Uri Are those template that **are not** showing the `{{ admin_user_prefix }}` rendered by a _custom_ template tag (`inclusion_tag`)?

Comment: I added `{{ admin_user_prefix }}` in the calling template right before `{% include 'admin/user_list_item.html' with user=user %}`, and then I can see the admin prefix printed. But changing it to `{% include 'admin/user_list_item.html' with user=user admin_user_prefix=admin_user_prefix %}` doesn't work.

Comment: @PedramParsian Actually you are correct. I'm sorry about the mistake, I was not aware but the problem is with a template rendered with an `inclusion_tag`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, this happened due to using `inclusion_tag` for rendering the template.

The problem is that they **don't have** any context variable, and as the result, the won't call your custom `context_processor`.

You should use `takes_context=True` in your template tag in order to make it accept context data.

The code that works now:

```
@register.inclusion_tag(filename='accounts/profile_picture.html', takes_context=True)
def profile_picture(context, user, geometry, with_link=True, html_class=''):
    context = copy.copy(context)
    context.update({
        'user': user,
        'geometry': geometry,
        'width': geometry.split('x')[0],
        'with_link': with_link,
        'html_class': html_class,
    })
    return context
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Do you mind if I edit your answer and add the code which works now?

Comment: I would be very grateful if you do so :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your context processor in settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
             ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'Your context processor' 
            ]
       }
   }
]
```

Comment: Yes I did. I already wrote that in some cases the prefix is printed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the context processor var you created in an included template, add before the inclusion:

```html
{% add_admin_user_prefix as add_admin_user_prefix %}
{% include "whatever.html" %}
```

I don't know why that must be done, but it worked for me for a package I was using (`django-postman`). Hopefully, your context var should then be accessible globally.

Comment: This raises an exception: `TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/users/
Invalid block tag on line 15: 'add_admin_user_prefix', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

Comment: Yep sorry actually the package `postman` defined this var via a templatetag, I forgot that.