# Custom Django context processor not returning any value

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I have written a custom context processor to return some frequently-used variables. I have followed multiple tutorials and read the official documentation, but nothing is happening: the context processor is either not loading or not returning any value. I am not getting any errors.

app name:
*auctions*

*context_processors.py*

```
def test_context_processor(request):
    return {
        'message': 'Hello, world.'
    }
```

*settings.py*

```
...

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'auctions.context_processors.test_context_processor'
            ],
        },
    },
]

...
```

*layout.html*

```
...

<h1>{{ test_context_processor.message }}</h1>

...
```

When I inspect the H1 element, it is empty - nothing was returned. It looks like this:

```
<h1></h1>
```

I have tried:

- loading the function in shell and trying it out (it works)
- Renaming the function
- Restarting server
- `{{ test_context_processor['message'] }}` (This generates an error)
- Complaining on SO

All I can think of is that every tutorial example is using the context processor to return a list of objects from a database, whereas I'm just returning a plain string value. But surely that can't matter, right? Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem and the solution here worked for me : [Use takes_context=True when using register.inclusion_tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59452521/5796086)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were "nearly there" with this, in your template:

```
{{ test_context_processor['message'] }}
```

The only problem with this is that context processors just add data directly to the template context - which is essentially a dictionary holding your template variables. They don't scope or namespace it under anything, certainly not a name corresponding to the name of the context processor.

So you just need to do this:

```
{{ message }}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why this was such a hard one for me to figure out. 'Preciate it!