# How to get the sum of a model field value from all the posts a user created in django base template?

Tags: mysql, django, django-templates

I have a `auth_user` model, and a `posts` model. the `posts` model has fields like: `id`, `author_id` and `likes`. All I need print `likes` values related to each `user` in the `base` template. like:

> {{  user.posts.likes  }}

or

> {{  user.user_id.posts.likes  }}

This is my posts model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = "posts"
    
    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes
```

however it does not work, while `{{ user.profile.image.url }}` (profile is another model which has `user_id`) works perfectly.
I am importing `base` templates to other templates like `{% extends "app/base.html" %}` so I don't see any place in backend to pass the `likes` values

Comment: Pleas add your models

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I added the model of `posts` 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're confusing a single `Post` for multiple `posts` and as a result there isn't an object to access.  A user only has one profile, but as your code indicates they can have multiple `posts` as the `author` ForeignKey would indicate.

```
{{ user.post_set }} <- is a manager
{{ user.post_set.all }} <- is a queryset
{{ user.post_set.all.0 }} <- is the first item of the queryset 
{{ user.post_set.all.0.likes }} <- should be the # of likes of the user's first post
```

#### Edit 1

The updated question could be restated as "how can I get the total number of likes a user has received via their posts"

There might be a way to accomplish that in the templates, but I think it's going to be difficult.  I would put that number together in the view code.  The key word that you're looking for is "aggregation"

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/

```
from django.db.models import Sum
...
# inside your view
total_likes = user.post_set.all().aggregate(Sum('likes'))
```

#### Edit 2

Absolutely right @melvyn

#### Edit 3

In order to apply this to all pages without modifying the views you're going to have to write a context processor.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

```
file: likes_context.py
from django.db.models import Sum

def likes_context_processor(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        posts = request.user.post_set.all()
        total_likes = posts.aggregate(Sum('likes'))
    else:
        total_likes = 0
    return {"total_likes": total_likes }
```

You'll need to locate that file appropriately and then add it to your context processors config in your `settings.py`

This might be helpful as well: [creating my own context processor in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893724/creating-my-own-context-processor-in-django)

Comment: Hi Mike, Thank you for your answer, I tried  `{{ user.posts.all.0.likes }} `, `{{ user.posts.all.0.title }}`, `{{ user.posts.all.0}}`,`{{ user.posts.all }}` and non of them return any result. Just `{{ user }}` returns the value of `username`

Comment: I just tried with `{{ posts.0.likes }}` and it returns the number of likes based on the first post of querysets which I passed to each template in the views.py. For example in first template 11, second 0, third 200 and so on... do you know how can I expect to sum up all likes of posts which user created? I tried with `{{ user.posts.all.likes |length }}` and didn't work!

Comment: Pssst: there is no `related_name`, so user.posts should be `user.post_set`.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for your update. As I am using likes in the header in base.html so I am not passing posts.queryset directly to base template so I guess I can't handle it in view.py. Do you know how to solve it in template?

Comment: @Mike Your answer is brilliant. It's working as I expect just one error occurs when I am trying to log out. as `'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'post_set'` which happens in the line `posts = request.user.post_set.all()` I tried to put skip it but all the code goes crazy even after shutting down the server which is weird!

Comment: Just updated to take that into account.  I guess I had assumed that everyone would be logged in to be able to see the page.  Just add a check for user.is_authenticated