# In Django templates, can I write a function or a custom tag to generate a dropdown, so I can reuse the same code in other templates?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

I want my django templates models agnostic.

Django **view** will massage the model data and send a list to the template

```
['item_1', 'item_2', 'item_3', .... 'item_n]
```

In the template, I want to convert this list of items into a HTML dropdown.

But since I shall be having this kind of behavior at many places I would like to reuse the code that is transforming the list into the dropdown.

How may I do that?

Comment: Why not use a `Form` and a `ModelChoiceField` if you want a select with model choices? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

Comment: Have you tried to use context processors? This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66051857/6119245) can help