# Django Template dynamically generated sidebar

Tags: django, django-templates, django-extensions

I have created a two django views home() and machine_detail(). Home view renders an home.html template and pass it a dictionary containing equipment names. my side bar consists of the items in this dictionary which is dynamically generated below these names. The equipment model is related to Machines model and I have used django foreign key relation to make a drop down for each equipment showing all the machines related to that specific equipment. all the machines are in an anchor tag and upon click i want to show a detail of machine page but why cant i see my side bar contents in machine detail template it is extending home.html but still the sidebar is not showing anyhting. please help me

Equipment Model

```
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()    
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    contractor = models.ForeignKey(Contractor, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
```

Machines Model

```
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type_of_machine = models.ForeignKey(Equipment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='typeOfMachine')
    spares = models.ManyToManyField(Spares,related_name='machines' ,blank=True)
    dop = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date of Purcahse", blank=True, null=True)
    purchase_cost = models.FloatField(default=0)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True)
```

Home View

```
def home(request):
    
    eq_map = {}
    equipment = models.Equipment.objects.all()
    for e in equipment:
        eq_map[e] = e.typeOfMachine.all()

    return render(request, "user/sidebar.html",{'equipments':eq_map})
```

machine_Detail view

```
def machine_detail(request,pk):
    machine_detail = models.Machines.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, "user/machine_detail.html", {"machine_detail":machine_detail})
```

home.html

```
        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            {% for equipment,machines in equipments.items %}
                    <li> {{equipment|safe}} <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        {% for m in machines  %}
                             <a href="{% url 'machineDetail' pk=m.pk %}"><li>{{m}}</li></a>  
                        {% endfor %}        
                    </li> 
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

machine-detail.html

```
{% extends "user/home.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
  Machine Detail
{% endblock title %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said before, your sidebar needs data in your dict "equipments".

This data could come from the current view in params added to the render function.

```
return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'sidebar_data': sidebar_data})
```

If you want to display it on several pages, you would have do provide this data in all views. The solution to your problem is to user a context processor which is a way to call a kind of global function from your template.

[creating my own context processor in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893724/creating-my-own-context-processor-in-django)